# Does priority exists between linux signals?

Tags: c, linux, networking, signals

My doubt is that if a process has received 5 different signals to it when it is not scheduled to the CPU and now suppose the process is scheduled to the CPU then out of the 5 signals which one will be handled first and why ?

Comment: No these are not interrupts, but software-signal there is no priority one over other...

Comment: If no priority between signals which signal is handled first and why?

Comment: @MKAMALKUMAR I am not adding an answer but Give you tow links: **First**: [Linux Programmer's Manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html): "If both standard and real-time signals are pending for a process, **POSIX leaves it unspecified which is delivered first.**  Linux, like many other implementations, gives priority to standard signals in this case."

Comment: **Second:** [Signals, Traps, and Interrupts](http://cis.poly.edu/muller/CS623/signalsintro.htm): "interrupts are often assigned different priorities, whereas, software signals are not"

Comment: @MKAMALKUMAR *`If no priority between signals which signal is handled first and why`*  --it is unspecified --http://cs-pub.bu.edu/fac/richwest/cs591_w1/notes/wk3_pt2.PDF

Comment: @Chauhan am satisfied with your answer "POSIX leaves it unspecified which is delivered first". Thank you.

Comment: @MKAMALKUMAR Your welcome, I will post an answer after collecting some more information. when I will find time.

Answer (score 0):

Posting Grijesh Chauhan's comment as an answer here, for posterity:

First: [Linux Programmer's Manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html): "If both standard and real-time signals are pending for a process, POSIX leaves it unspecified which is delivered first. Linux, like many other implementations, gives priority to standard signals in this case."

Second: [Signals, Traps, and Interrupts](http://cis.poly.edu/muller/CS623/signalsintro.htm): "interrupts are often assigned different priorities, whereas, software signals are not"